# How to create a ZIP file with WinRAR with name of ZIP file being name of current folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a `.bat` file that will zip select files with a filename that automatically matches the current folder name and a custom extension.

For example, within directory `C:\thisIsAFolder\`

```
Winrar a -afzip %thisIsAFolder%.PicZip *.jpg *.png *.gif
```

I was trying to use `%CD%`, but it doesn't work, possible due to a terminator at the end?

This is a small part of a larger batch file, but it is the only part that doesn't work.

I am open to an alternative to using a batch file.

Comment: Put `echo on` just above the problem line and see what it outputs.  Does that command look right?

Comment: Going to assume you are trying to get the parent directory name into a variable. `for %%a in ("%~dp0\..") do set parent=%%~nxa`

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the echo suggestion, the problem was the complete pathname being included; c:/etc.

Comment: Squashman, that was a great suggestion, it works for the parent folder, but I'm after the current folder. If I were to want to learn this, what subject would I study?

Comment: @user3369147, remove one dot.  That is basic cmd prompt syntax.  One period is the current folder.  Two periods is the parent folder.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @Squashman What subject can I study to learn this Code Fu? Is this learned in Powershell?

Comment: @Frodofeet Just a general debugging tip for batch: Don't debug with echo off.  It's like trying to perform surgery on an epileptic in the dark.  :)

Comment: The parent directory of the batch script (`%~dp0`) and the current working directory `%CD%`) are two different things! So what is it you want?

Comment: Yeah, I'm apparently not familiar with batch scripting syntax at all. I had no idea what %%a, %~dp0, or %%~nxa meant. Great to know that there is always more to learn! :D

Comment: @Frodofeet, you can use the `%CD%` variable in the code I gave you as well.

Answer (score 0):

This batch code could be used for this task:

```
@echo off
if not "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
    for /F %%I in ("%CD%") do set "FolderName=%%~nxI"
) else (
    set "FolderName=Drive%CD:~0,1%"
)
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip -cfg- -ibck -m0 -y "%FolderName%.PicZip" *.jpg *.png *.gif
set FolderName=
```

**Note:** The path to `WinRAR.exe` can be different on your machine depending on installation of *WinRAR*.

The environment variable `CD` holds the path to current directory. This path does not end with a backslash, except the current directory is the root directory of a drive.

The **IF** condition compares last character of current directory path with a backslash. Is the last character NOT a backslash, the command **FOR** is used to get from entire directory path the string after last backslash which is the name of the current directory. Otherwise the current directory is a root directory of a drive and name for folder is defined as `Drive` with drive letter appended.

The ZIP file is created with compression method `store` because of switch `-m0` as *.jpg, *.png and *.gif files contain already compressed data and therefore a re-compression does not make much sense.

For an explanation of the switches open in *WinRAR* from menu **Help** the **Help topics**. On tab **Contents** open list item **Command line mode** and subitem **Switches**. Open help page **Alphabetic switches list** and read about the switches.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `if /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`